# AzCopy Command Util Syntax Error keeps happening

Tags: azcopy, blobstorage

I am beginner to AzCopy and my question is very basic. But I cannot solve.
I Am trying to copy certain all data in directory in Local PC(or VM) to Azure BLob Storage.

I tried following in powershell.

```
AzCopy /Source:C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\transfertest\ /Dest:https//shinstorages.core.windows.net/branko/ /DestKey:mykey /S
```

I Get error
The syntax of the command is incorrect. Data transfer from local system to local system is not supp
orted.
At line:1 char:1
+ AzCopy /Source:C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\transfertest\ /Dest: ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: ([2019/06/20 18:... not supported.:String) [], RemoteException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

I think I have following syntax rule. But I cannot find where is syntax error.
Please, help me!

Comment: You're missing a colon in the Dest parameter. `https//shinst` should be `https://shinst`.

Comment: Thankyou. It's solved...

Comment: @reportgunner, please post your comment as an answer, it would be helpful for others.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a colon in the `Dest` parameter.

`https//shinst` should be `https://shinst`

`AzCopy /Source:C:\Users\mypc\Desktop\transfertest\ /Dest:https://shinstorages.core.windows.net/branko/ /DestKey:mykey /S`